# Combining importance sampling with optimization - does this yield an unbiased estimate?

Tags: monte-carlo, unbiased-estimator, importance-sampling

I'm wondering if it is OK to combine importance sampling with optimization to choose the parameters for the substitute distribution.

I have a non-negative random variable $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with pdf $p(x)$, and I want to estimate $\mathbb{E}[X]$.  $X$ is close to zero for everywhere except a small region of $\mathbb{R}^d$, which makes it harder to estimate $\mathbb{E}[X]$ through random sampling.  When $d$ is large, evaluating the integral $\int_x x p(x)\, dx$ is expensive, so I am looking for more efficient methods.  I know that $f$ is sharply concentrated: i.e., it is zero mostly everywhere, except for a small region where it is large.

I've come up with following method for estimating $\mathbb{E}[X]$.  I am going to use importance sampling with some substitute distribution $q(x)$, using the fact that

$$\mathbb{E}_{X \sim p}[X] = \mathbb{E}_{X' \sim q}[X' p(X')/q(X')].$$

Next I will try to find a substitute distribution $q$ that gives me the best estimate.  In particular, I will let $q$ be a multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\sigma$.  Then I will optimize over $\mu,\sigma$, letting

$$\mu^*,\sigma^* := \arg \max_{\mu,\sigma} \mathbb{E}_{X' \sim q_{\mu,\sigma}}[X' p(X')/q_{\mu,\sigma}(X')].$$

Finally, I will estimate $\mathbb{E}_{X' \sim q_{\mu^*,\sigma^*}}[X' p(X')/q_{\mu^*,\sigma^*}(X')]$ by sampling a value of $x'$ from $q_{\mu^*,\sigma^*}$ and computing $x' p(x')/q_{\mu^*,\sigma^*}(x')$ (or sampling a few values and taking the average) and using this as my estimate for $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

---

My question: Is this an unbiased estimate of $\mathbb{E}[X]$?

My doubt: we're choosing $\mu^*,\sigma^*$ somehow based on $p$, so it feels "not independent" and that makes me worry that it might cause a bias.

Follow-up question: Is there a better way to use optimization to make a better choice of $\mu^*,\sigma^*$ that will give a lower-variance estimate of $\mathbb{E}[X]$?

Comment: this recent talk might be interesting to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH04DKnZJ-U

Answer (score 2):

The solution remains unbiased as $(\mu^\star,\sigma^\star)$ does not depend on the sample from $q_{\mu^\star,\sigma^\star}(\cdot)$.

The optimisation$$\mu^*,\sigma^* := \arg \max_{\mu,\sigma} \mathbb{E}_{X' \sim q_{\mu,\sigma}}[X' p(X')/q_{\mu,\sigma}(X')]$$does not make sense since
$$\mathbb{E}_{X' \sim q_{\mu,\sigma}}[X' p(X')/q_{\mu,\sigma}(X')]=\mathbb{E}_{X \sim p}[X]$$for all $(\mu,\sigma)$. One alternative is to minimise the variance
$$\mu^*,\sigma^* := \arg \min_{\mu,\sigma} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim q_{\mu,\sigma}}[X^2p(X)^2/q_{\mu,\sigma}(X)^2]$$which leads to $q_{\mu,\sigma}(x)\propto |x|p(x)|$ if feasible; another to bring $q_{\mu,\sigma}$ as close as possible to $p$:
$$\mu^*,\sigma^* := \arg \min_{\mu,\sigma} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim q_{\mu,\sigma}}[\log q_{\mu,\sigma}(X)/p(X)]$$
or
$$\mu^*,\sigma^* := \arg \min_{\mu,\sigma} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim p}[\log p(X)/q_{\mu,\sigma}(X)]:= \arg \max_{\mu,\sigma} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim p}[\log q_{\mu,\sigma}(X)]$$

Comment: Thank you!  Those are excellent points.  (I think the reason why the maximization superficially seemed to make sense is that I'm estimating the expectation by taking a few samples; and because $X$ is close to zero for everywhere except a small region of $\mathbb{R}^d$, the sampling-based estimate tends to underestimate the true expectation unless $q_{\mu,\sigma}$ is close to $p$.  But your proposals make more sense.  Thank you!)

Comment: What made you choose $\mathbb{E}[\log q_{\mu,\sigma}(X) / p(X)]$ rather than, say, the KL between $q_{\mu,\sigma}$ and $p$?  e.g., $\mathbb{E}[\log (q_{\mu,\sigma}(X) / p(X))]$?  Or perhaps that is already what you meant?  Do you have any advice on how you would choose between these two ways of measuring how close $q_{\mu,\sigma}$ is to $p$?  Thank you again!

Comment: Yes I meant the Kullback-Leibler.

Comment: Can you help me understand why making $q_{\mu,\sigma}$ similar to $p$ is a useful/sensible thing to do?  I've seen results that the optimal $q(x)$ is proportional to $x p(x)$ (optimal in the sense of minimizing variance).  Is there a sense in which using $q$ that is most similar to $p$ is a good choice?  In the extreme, where $q=p$, it seems this offers no advantage over ordinary sampling from $p$, so I'm struggling to understand.  I'm happy to ask this as a separate question if you think that's more suitable.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: It all depends on the chosen criterion. If using Kullback with $xp(x)$, $xp(x)$ need be normalised into a density.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm still confused.  We can't really use KL with $xp(x)$, because normalizing it requires computing $\mathbb{E}[X]$, which is exactly the problem we're trying to solve, so that's not an option.  So getting close to $x p(x)$ would be useful, but we can't do it.  I realize that $p(x)$ *is* normalized, but why is it a good distribution to try to get close to?  Is there some argument that $p(x)$ is somewhat similar to a normalized version of $x p(x)$, and $x p(x)$ is optimal, which is why it's useful to get close to $p(x)$?  I suspect I'm missing something.